# If $\|\left(f'(x)\right)^{-1}\|\le 1 \Longrightarrow$ $f$ is an diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n,f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n\;,\;f'(x)$ is an isomorphism and:

$$ \|\left(f'(x)\right)^{-1}\|\le 1\;,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

How can we prove that  $f$ is a diffeomorphism ?

---

Author's suggestion:

$\forall [f(a),\color{red}b]\subset \mathbb{R}^n,\exists \lambda:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lambda(0)=a$ and $f(\lambda(t))=(1-t)f(a)+t\color{red}b$

therefore $f$ is surjective.

Note that  $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, the strong part is to show that $f$ is injective.

There is a proof without using homotopy ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Even worse: $x=(0,0)$ and $y=(0,2n\pi)$ with $n\to\infty$, for the same function $f$.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I edited it.

Comment: Did you forget to assume that $f$ is injective?

Comment: @studiosus I think the first part is to show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism onto $\mathbb{R}^n$, without assuming that $f$ is injective.

Comment: What is the problem with the answer of @smiley06?

Comment: @Tomás How to prove that $f$ is injective?

Comment: I see, he proved only that the function is surjective.

Comment: My comment was wrong, I have deleted it.

Comment: @Tomás Se o exercício é de Elon análise real, see reference Corollary 6.13 homotopy general proof http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/lima.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume here what @smiley06 has proved in his answer. With it, I will prove that for every continuous curve $\beta:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$, there exist a unique $\lambda$ continuous such that $f(\lambda(t))=\beta(t)$. Indeed, let $\beta:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous curve. For each $t$ consider the segment of line $$\ell(t,r)=(1-r)\beta(0)+r\beta(t),\ r\in [0,1]$$

For each $t$, there exist (this is the proof of @smiley06) $\lambda (t,r)$ such that $f(\lambda(t,r))=l(t,r)$. Now define $\lambda (t)=\lambda (t,1)$ which implies that $$f(\lambda (t))=l(t,1)=\beta(t)$$

Assume now that $f(x)=f(y)$ and let $\alpha (t)=(1-t)x+ty$. Consider $F:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $$F(\eta,t)=(1-\eta)f(\alpha(t))+\eta f(y)$$

For each fixed $\eta$ let $G(\eta,t)$ be a curve (which exists as we have proved above) such that $f(G(\eta,t))=F(\eta,t)$ and $G(\eta,0)=x$. Note that $$f(G(\eta,1))=f(y),\ \forall\ \eta\in [0,1]\tag{1}$$

Because $f$ is a local diffeomorphim we conclude from $(1)$ that $G(\eta,1)=y$ for all $\eta\in [0,1]$ which implies that $y=x$.

Comment: .@Tomás The sequence $x_k$ is cauchy? could you explain?

Comment: I have edite the answer, please take a look. Essa questão é um saco, onde você estuda?

Comment: .@Tomás  é um exercício de Elon análise real, see reference exercise 8.14 page 342 http://www.filefactory.com/file/4qhynuf4lohl/curso_de_analise_volume_2.pdf

Comment: É, eu sei qual é, já tinha feito ele há algum tempo atrás. É um problema interessante, mas eu acho que não tem como resolvê-lo completamente sem usar um pouco de espaços de recobrimento.

Comment: .@Tomás also known as Hadamard-Plastock  theorem http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/balreira/research/Balreira_UG_slides.pdf

Comment: .@Tomás the solution of @smiley06 is local or global in all $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: It is global in $[0,1]$. First you apply Peano theorem to find a solution. Then, you can note that the solution is unique because $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. To conclude, you can extend this solution globally because $\|f^{-1}\|$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: .@Tomás could you explain why $G(\eta,1)=y$ for all $\eta\in [0,1]$ ?$ , G(\eta,1)\in f^{-1}(b)$ discrete set where $b=f(x)=f(y)$

Comment: @felipeuni, you have to note two things. The first one is the fact that $G$ is continuous. The second is the fact that $G(0,1)=y$. Because $f$ is a local diffeo, every point close to $y$ but diffrent from $y$ has a image different from $f(y)$, hence, if $f(G(\eta,1))=f(y)$ then $G(\eta,1)=y$ .

Comment: .@Tomás could you explain why $G(\eta,t)$ is continuous ? this condition is strong.

Comment: Did you tried to prove it? It is not hard to prove it, try to explore for example the fact that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, $F$ is continuous (in fact $F$ is $C^1$) and remember that the notion of conitnuity is local (also use the fact that $G$ is implicitly defined by the equation f(G)=F). Even more I can say: $G$ is $C^1$.

Comment: .@Tomás Ok Tomás, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Tomás, an observation: $G(\eta,0)=x$ for all $\eta\in [0,1]$ ? I think the correct thing $G(0,0)=x$. On the other hand because $G(\eta,1)=y$ for all $\eta\in [0,1]$ implies that $y=x$? I appreciate it clears the doubt.

Comment: @helmonio, every curve $G(\eta,\cdot)$ starts in the point $x$, hence $G(\eta,0)=x$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Tomás, It is true! is this using the fact that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: @helmonio, note that $F(\eta,0)=f(x)=f(y)$ for all $\eta$, hence, the curve $G(\eta,\cdot)$ can choosen in such a way that $G(\eta,0)=x$ for all $\eta$.

Comment: @Tomás, Only one more because $G(η,1)=y$ for all $η∈[0,1]$ implies that $y=x$?

Comment: @helmonio, because the curve $G(1,\lambda)$ is constant and equal $x$ for all $\lambda$.

Comment: @Tomás, many thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the operator norm $ \|f'(x)\| \geq 1 $, hence $ f'(x)$ is invertible for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $, from existence theorem of ODEs there exists $ \lambda : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ satisfying
$$ \lambda'(t) = (f'(\lambda(t))^{-1}(b-f(a)),\ \ \ \lambda(0) = a $$
Hence we have the relation
$$ \begin{align}f(\lambda(t)) = f(\lambda(0)) + \int^t_0 (f\circ\lambda)'(s)ds\\ = f(a) + \int^t_0 f'(\lambda(s))(\lambda'(s))ds\\
=f(a) + \int^t_0 (b-f(a))ds= (1-t)f(a) +tb \end{align}$$