# Properties of a surjective local diffeomorphism

Tags: analysis

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$ is a surjective function and in addition suppose that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. Take two points in the image of $f$, let's say, $f(x),f(y)$ with $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

Is it possible to find a continuous curve $\alpha :[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^N$ such that $\alpha(0)=x$, $\alpha(1)=y$ and $f(\alpha (t))=(1-t)f(x)+tf(y)$.

Remark: This question is related to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485050/if-leftfx-right-1-le-1-longrightarrow-f-is-an-diffeomorphism?noredirect=1#comment1081950_485050)

Remark 1: The answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485050/if-leftfx-right-1-le-1-longrightarrow-f-is-an-diffeomorphism?noredirect=1#comment1081950_485050) by @smiley06, solves this problem, when only one boundary condition is prescribed.

Thank you

Comment: You're basically asking whether $f$ has to be a covering. For $N\geq2$ it is not true.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @user8268. Could you please give me a example?

Comment: Do you have any example of such a $f$ that is not invertible? I can't think of any.

Comment: I'll try to draw one

Comment: well and for which $(x,y)$ is $f(x,y)= (0,0)$ ??

Comment: @tom, ops... I forget it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $N=2$; I replace $\mathbb R^2$ with a disk (as it is diffeomorphic); here is a surjective map from a disk to a "disk" (still diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$) and a straight segment that can't be lifted.

[image: really horrible picture]

Comment: Sorry about my dumbness, but could you add some explanation. Thank you

Comment: I know that picture is impossible; try yourself to map a disk to the plane so that the image is a disk, but the map is not 1-1.

Comment: Very nice! I like it.

Comment: Are all that "loops" necessary? Disclaimer: I am not specialist.

Comment: Yes the loops are necessary. Look at my animation. You take disk first deform it to the O shape and with one end you fill the hole in the O.

Answer (score 3):

All the credit goes to the user8268 but I made a little animation.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to fill the inside of the disk.

Comment: Thank you @tom for your kindness. Now I can see, hahah.

Comment: wow! How did you do it?

Comment: I used Autodes Maya, but it is "a little" bit overkill(most of the Avatar scenes were done in it :D). I guess it can be done in something like Flash.