# Basic question on n-dimensional derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ , suppose that $f \in C^{2}(\mathbb R^n)$ and  suppose too $\inf_{\mathbb R^n} |\nabla f | \geq \alpha > 0$ for some $\alpha$. My intuition says this

$$  |f(x) - f(y)| \geq \alpha |x-y|$$

for $x$, $y \in \mathbb R^n$. I tried a for a good time to prove this (I tried the mean value theorem, cauchy schwarz, but nothing worked ..).  i am not seeing how to prove or disprove my affirmation. Someone can give me a help?

thanks in advance

Comment: False, consider $f((x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)) = x_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate you did not consider any examples while *trying for a good time*. There is **no** smooth function on $\mathbb R^n$, $n>1$ that satisfies this estimate. One way to show this is to invoke the implicit function theorem: fix $x_0$; then the set $\{x : f(x)=f(x_0)\}$ is locally a smooth surface. The inequality fails for every $y\ne x_0$ on this surface.

---

The following is true, however. Suppose $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is an injective $C^1$ map such that for every $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and every vector $v\in \mathbb R^n$ we have 
$$|Df(x) v|\ge \alpha |v|$$ 
(Here $Df(x)$ is the derivative matrix.) Then $$|f(x)-f(y)|\ge \alpha |x-y|$$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$.

**Proof:** Consider $g=f^{-1}$, observe that $\|Dg\|\le \alpha^{-1}$ everywhere; use the Mean Value Inequality for $g$.

The assumption of injectivity can be dropped at the expense of some extra work: see [If $\|\left(f'(x)\right)^{-1}\|\le 1 \Longrightarrow$ $f$ is an diffeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/485050/).

Comment: It is worth to note that this result still valid, even if $f$ is not assumed to be injective. Indeed, we have http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485050/if-leftfx-right-1-le-1-longrightarrow-f-is-an-diffeomorphism/505041#505041

Comment: You are welcome!